# No Response from Register.php?

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I am attempting to set up a simple register user within an app that will eventually allow users to search for local bands and the venues at which they are playing.

I had it where I could enter the register information, click "Register," and return to sign-in page. After trying to link the app with a database, the clicking the "Register" button does nothing unless I comment out the "Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener()" section of the onClick method.

So, it appears as though I am not receiving a response from Register.php.(?)

When I comment out the "Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener()" section of the onClick method, I can get things to happen. So, that's why I believe I've narrowed the issue down to that section of code.

My RegisterActivity class:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etName = findViewById(R.id.text_register_name);
    final EditText etUsername = findViewById(R.id.text_register_username);
    final EditText etPassword = findViewById(R.id.text_register_password);
    final Button btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

My RegisterRequest class:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://bandsearch.000webhostapp.com/public_html/Band/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest (String name, String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params;
}
```

My Register.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id11439356_btpeters', 'demopass', 'id11439356_localmusic');

// $name = "Brent"; //$_POST['name']; 
// $username = "Vegasbrent"; //$_POST['username']; 
// $password = "pass"; //$_POST['password']; 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

if (mysqli_query($connect, $statement)) {
    $response["success"] = true;   
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I expect the user table in my database to populate when the "Register" button is clicked and that the app returns to the sign-in page, but clicking "Register" button doesn't do either.

EDIT: I believe I have further narrowed the issue down to the $_POST section:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

I can add to the user table in the database if I set the variables to strings instead of $_POST[...]. It may have to do with the getParams method because I never call it. I assumed it was called automatically somewhere. I'll check it out and see if I can figure it out! Any help is appreciated, though!

EDIT: getParams method is automatically called by Volley. Trying now to figure out how to check if Volley called getParams method!